# Is there a plugin or another way to quicky edit the attribute features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, fields-attributes

I want to edit the field "name" of several roads in QGIS 2.14.

How to do it very quickly?

Currently I select with "Identity feature" tool that open Form Feature Attribute, then with the mouse I must search the "name" field, type new name and hit enter, but the form stay open in the background.

There's a way when I select the feature jump right to the "name" field, start typing right away and close the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the "QuickMultiAttributeEdit" plugin available on the official plugin repository.  Simply use the select tool to pick which features you want to edit, then click the plugin, and it comes up with a drop down menu of fields, and a box to enter the new value.  This lets you edit a feature without ever needing to open the attribute table (especially useful with really big tables that are slow to load)

Comment: Underful **wmebane**. Is there a way to automatic open "QuickMultiAttributeEdit"  without using F12 key?

Even works fine what @bgramm suggested and I fine tuned, this is better.

Answer (score 2):

Carlos,

You may want to try changing the order of the attribute fields so your road name field is the first in the list.

You can do this with the table manager, or in the processing toolbox under QGIS Vector Table editing you can use Refactor to change the order of the fields. The Refactor option will create a copy of the original data file, and open it as Refactor.

Sorry I am not able to provide pictures at this time, but this has worked for me on numerous occasions, and it does not take long at all.

Comment: I follow your suggestion @jbgramm; Vector > Table manager.   

But I must put the field in the second position and hit TAB key to jump to the next field, in this case, my field "name" in that way it auto select the NULL value, because the first  field is highlighted but when start typing it includes the string NULL and I must select it to delete.

So it is better to put the field in the second place.

Many tanks.

Comment: Carlos,
You are welcome!
I am sorry that it does not do exactly what you want, but I am glad to have helped.